# WordPress Trouble integrating Ajax functionality

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a WP *Fiche* page with a plugin. 
The content of this page requires many variables and functions that are contained in another file `important_file.php`. That's why I put everything in the `content_fiche()` function and I use `require_once('important_file.php')`.

The problem is that I want to manage the forms of my page content with JQuery Ajax and call the functions contained in the file `important_file.php`.

I don't really want to modify the file `important_file.php` as I didn't code it.

```
<?php
class fiche_content{
    private $file_base;

    function __construct(){
        $this->file_base = plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'fiche.php'; 
        $this->init();
    }   

    function init() {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'scripts_js'));
        add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'add_page_fiche'));
    }  

    function scripts_js(){
        wp_enqueue_script('fiche_scripts', plugins_url('JS/scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_localize_script('fiche_scripts', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'fiche.php' ),
        ));
    }

    function add_page_fiche() {
        $new_page = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Fiche Projet' ),
            'post_content'  => $this->content_fiche(),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'page'
        );
        wp_insert_post( $new_page );
    }    

    function content_fiche(){
        require_once ( '.../important_file.php');
        $foo = $var_in_important_file;      
        $html = '<div>'. $foo .'</div>';
        $html .= '<form id="form" method="POST">
                      <input type="hidden" name="build" value="1" />
                      <input type="submit" name="submit_build" value="Submit" />
                </form>';
        return $html;
```

Here my JS file which should manage the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('submit', '#form',function(e){
        $.post({
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                data,
                'action': 'function_in_important_file'
            },
            done: function(result) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

To connect my JS submit to the PHP functions, I usually just do, but gere it's not enough:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_function_in_important_file', 'function_in_important_file' );
```

Obviously the ajax file cannot access the `important_file.php` and its functions. It's my first time with OOP plugin, so how should I proceed, I have no idea.

Comment: How have you set up the Ajax url endpoint? Why can you not include `important_file` in the code that generates the Ajax response? Are you using WP_Ajax_Repsonse? Or the Rest API?

Comment: I'd like to use in my `content_fiche()` function some variables which are in my `important_file`. If I include a second time my `important_file` in the content of the Ajax response, it will throw an error as functions of `important_file` are already declared.
The Ajax URL endpoint is just the PHP file which contains the class, I edited my post. Strangely, when I click on the submit of the form, it deletes my page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the handbook on [WordPress Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) functions

```
    class fiche_content{
        private $file_base;

        function __construct(){
            $this->file_base = plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'fiche.php'; 
            $this->init();
        }   

        function init() {
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'scripts_js'));
            //add_action('wp_loaded', array($this, 'add_page_fiche'));

            // Register the Ajax action to bind the corresponding WordPress function

            add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_function_in_important_file", array ( $this, 'add_page_fiche' ) );
            add_action( "wp_ajax_function_in_important_file",        array ( $this, 'add_page_fiche' ) );



        }  

        function scripts_js(){
            wp_enqueue_script('fiche_scripts', plugins_url('JS/scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
            wp_localize_script('fiche_scripts', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'fiche.php' ),
            ));
        }

        function add_page_fiche() {
            $new_page = array(
                'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Fiche Projet' ),
                'post_content'  => $this->content_fiche(),
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                'post_type'     => 'page'
            );
            wp_insert_post( $new_page );
        }    

        function content_fiche(){
            require_once ( '.../important_file.php');
            $foo = $var_in_important_file;      
            $html = '<div>'. $foo .'</div>';
            $html .= '<form id="form" method="POST">
                          <input type="hidden" name="build" value="1" />
                          <input type="submit" name="submit_build" value="Submit" />
                    </form>';
            return $html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the purpose of what you added. My page creation works correctly, the problem is I think the integration of the `important_file.php` and its functions. If I include my file in my `content_fiche()` function then I can't include it elsewhere (because its functions would be declared several times) and couldn't use its variables/functions elsewhere

Comment: *" If I include my file in my content_fiche() function then I can't include it elsewhere"* -- That's why we have [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)/[`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Comment: @George Well said

Comment: yes @George, that's why I'm asking here if there is another solution for me